WPF 3d rendering of intersecting semi-transparent surfaces
I'm using Helix Toolkit in a WPF application to provide some visualisation for an engineering tool. I am a beginner with 3d graphics.
I'd like to display some circles in 3d space as tinted "planar" surfaces. It is expected that these circles will intersect. For purposes of reliable visualisation, I'm actually modelling these as thin, wide cylinders using Helix's MeshBuilder.AddCylinder() (not as true planes), and then creating a GeometryModel3D from the MeshGeometry3D. The GeometryModel3D's Material is created using Helix's MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Color color, double opacity) method, which creates a compound material with both diffuse and specular components.
When the cylinders are rendered, the cylinder which was added to the model last renders its transparency over the previous cylinder correctly, but not vice versa. This appears to be due to a well-known limitation of the core WPF rendering engine (EDIT: actually, all 3d APIs which use depth buffers to track occlusion, including OpenGL and DirectX) - the correctness of the transparency calculation depends on objects being rendered in descending order of distance from the camera.
The usual fixes given in related questions on SO generally advise (re-)sorting the transparent objects in visual back-to-front order depending on current camera viewpoint, so that WPF renders the transparency correctly. As suggested in this question Helix even includes a helper named SortingVisual3D which implements this behaviour. But that solution can't work for two intersecting plane-like objects, since the z-order will vary depending on which part of the image you're looking at, as shown in this image:

In this image, the red and green cylinders are both centered on the coordinate system origin, with the red cylinder's "normal vector" aligned with the X axis and the green cylinder's "normal vector" aligned with the Y axis. The objects are added to the scene in the following order:

Grid lines
Origin indication arrows
Red cylinder
Green cylinder

In the part of the image where the green cylinder is in front of the red cylinder, the colours are blended correctly. But where the red cylinder is in front of the green cylinder, the green colour isn't visible at all (but the grid is still visible through the red, showing that the red cylinder is indeed still semi-transparent).
I think I might be able to solve the problem by slicing the intersecting cylinders along their planes of intersection, into separate GeometryModel3D objects with independent meshes, which can then be sorted by depth using SortingVisual3D. This would allow the correct ordering of the transparency for each overlapping arrangement. How can this slicing be accomplished?

Does this answer your question? OpenGL: Rendering two transparent planes intersecting each other: impossible or not?

Although that question definitely has the same root cause, the linked question contains 0 zero information about how its solutions could be applied to Helix Toolkit/WPF 3D APIs. It is not a solution to my problem.
I'm not writing against OpenGL APIs. (I'm pretty sure WPF uses DirectX under the hood on Windows).
I already listed "splitting the GeometryModel3Ds into separate objects and sorting them by depth" as a potential strategy, but I don't know how to actually do that.

However the linked question probably does imply that switching from WPF's rendering engine to SharpDX won't make any immediate difference.

I've narrowed the question to make it less open-ended - I've removed the other two potential solution strategies that I thought might have been possible.

Your issue is caused by depth buffer culling. You need to use helix toolkit sharpdx version and use order independent transparency render pass.
